# In my apple account I am not getting Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles option.provisioning profile error in xcode8

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having valid certificate which will expire next year.When creating app i am getting Failed to create provisioning profile and No profiles for 'com.codewithsuchi.WarGame' were found.I checked my account in xcode preferences ,but no provision profile.[image]
[image]

[image: Though I am having valid certificate why this is coming.]

Answer (score 0):

Did you finished your enrollment to the Apple Developer Program? It seems that you didn't finish some final steps. In your second screenshot it is obvious that you have to do some things here -> To continue your enrollment, **complete your purchase now**!

You should select this link and do the remaining stuff. Then it should work.

Comment: But I am having valid certificate.Now I am facing this problem.I think after upgrade to xcode 8.